# How do I sort Slackbot messages?

Tags: python, flask, slack

I want to make a Slack bot in Python with the following 2 functions.

1. If I type "(arbitrary character string)++", only "(arbitrary character string)" without ++ is returned.
2. If I hit "/karma_rank", "(arbitrary character string)" will be displayed in order of appearance count

The bot itself seems to start without any errors, but it has a "Counter" at the head and a dictionary format in the tuple, so it's in a state where I have no idea what to do.
And currently it does not react unless you type "++(arbitrary character string)".

If you know a solution, please let me know.
Thanking you in advance.

#### Current output

```
Counter({'abc': 10, 'def': 9, 'ghi': 8, 'jkl': 7, 'mno': 6, 'pqr': 5, 'stu': 4, 'vwx': 3, 'yz1': 2, '234': 1})
```

#### Ideal output

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz1
234
```

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from collections import Counter
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

data = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hoo'

#When input "++ abc", returned "abc". (Outgoing-webhook)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def shukei():
    text = request.form.get('text')
    moji = text.strip("+")
    data.append(moji)
    payload = {'text': moji}
    return jsonify(payload)

#How do I sort message?
@app.route('/karma_rank', methods=['POST'])
def slash():
    counter = str(Counter(data))
    payload = {'text': counter}
    return jsonify(payload)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

#### Additional information

iOS 10.15, Python 3.7.4, Atom

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```py
yourtuple =({'abc': 10, 'def': 9, 'ghi': 8, 'jkl': 7, 'mno': 6, 'pqr': 5, 'stu': 4,'vwx': 3, 'yz1': 2, '234': 1})
print ([mykey for mykey in (list(yourtuple))])
```